# Python regex remove all before a certain point

Tags: python, regex, string

Let's say I got a string:

```
F:\\Somefolder [2011 - 2012]\somefile
```

And I want to use regex to remove everything before: `somefile`

So the string I get is:

```
somefile
```

I tried to look at the regular expression sheet, but i cant seem to get it.
Any help is great.

Comment: are you trying to parse file names? Or is this just a generic example?

Comment: This is just an example. I want to remove everything from a string before the slash, including the slash.

Comment: Seems like this is a job for `os.path.basename` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want a regex here...

```
your_string.rpartition('\\')[-1]
```

Comment: Looks like this was the easiest way. And it works like a charm. I'm not very well known with Python yet. Still learning. Byt this was really helpful. Didn't know i could use something other than regex.
But now i know! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the part to the right of some character, you don't need a regular expression:

```
f = r"F:\Somefolder [2011 - 2012]\somefile" 
print f.rsplit("\\", 1)[-1]
#  somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this little guy?

```
[^\\]+$
```

... in action ...

```
myStr = "F:\Somefolder [2011 - 2012]\somefile"
result = re.match( r'[^\\]+$', myStr, re.M|re.I)
if result:
   print result.group(0)
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

Adapted from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Python RegEx Tester: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I've got it like you want remove part of string before some point-word ("somefile" in your example)

```
>> a = 'F:\\Somefolder [2011 - 2012]\somefile'
>> point = 'somefile'
>> print a[a.index(point):]
somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import Iterable

def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) -> Iterable:
    return items[items.index(border):] if border in items else items

print(remove_all_before((1,2,3,4,5,6), 3))
```

Comment: If you [edit] your answer and add an explanation as to how your code answers the question, it will make your answer much more valuable to others and more likely to be upvoted.